# php isset minus two variables

Tags: php, isset

Morning,

I am relatively new to PHP and I am having a bit of trouble with this line of PHP I have. I know its going to be something really simple and I am probably missing a character, but I'm just not understanding the layout of the code, so its not working.

```
<td><?=isset($aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count'])
-isset($aActivity['cancellations'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count'])

?$aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count']
-$aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count']:'0'?></td>
```

So I have the sales counting up how many a person has done, and minusing this off the amount of cancellations the same person has done, but its not working.

thanks in advance

Comment: well its not morning for more than half of world :)!

Comment: Thanks, my eyes are bleeding now. Insert some whitespace for gods sake, code is for humans to *read*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're subtracting the result of two `isset` operations. `isset` returns `true` or `false`. In a subtraction, `true` is seen as `1` and `false` as `0`. If both values are `true`, the result will be `0`, which is seen as `false` in the `?:` condition. If only one value is `true`, the result is `1` or `-1`, both of which are `true`. If both values are `false`, the result is `0`/`false`.

I'm guessing you want `&&` instead of `-`.

```
isset($a) && isset($b) ? $a - $b : 0
```

Incidentally this can be shortened to:

```
isset($a, $b) ? $a - $b : 0
```

Comment: $a - $b will no longer work in PHP 8.

Comment: @BrettStack1 Wat?

Comment: The - minus operator no longer works in PHP 8

Comment: @Brett You’ll have to provide some really concrete example for how exactly *the __minus operator__* “doesn’t work” anymore in PHP 8…! That’s one of the most basic operators in any language!

Answer (score 0):

What's that code?  Short tags should be rather used to display value not to create complex statements. You should rather use such code

```
<td><?php


if (isset($aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count']) && isset($aActivity['cancellations'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count'])) {
  echo $aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count'] -$aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count']
}
else {
   echo '0'
}?></td>
```

The main problem with your code is subtraction of 2 `isset`. Even if both are set you will get `1-1` which gives you 0 , so you should use code above and use '&&' operator instead.

If you don't want to mix complex PHP code with displaying (what is the best option), you should simple do:

```
<?php

$toDisplay = 0;
    if (isset($aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count']) && isset($aActivity['cancellations'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count'])) {
      $toDisplay = $aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count'] -$aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count']
    }
?>
```

And somewhere later in your code (where you want to display value):

```
<td><?= $toDisplay; ?></td>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Macin, I can use all of these replies to advance my understanding of PHP. I would add reputation but I am new to this forum :)

Answer (score 0):

First why are you subtracting isset of both. If both have some values in it then

```
isset($aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count'])-isset($aActivity['cancellations'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count'])
```

will return 0

Also if the condition is satisfied the result you want to echo will always give 0

```
$aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count']-$aActivity['sales'][$aNegtiator['nname']]['count']
```

Both the variables are same

Also check if your short tags are enabled in your php.ini file

Comment: Yeah, I didn't understand that I could subtract the isset from another isset. I wasn't sure of the proper way of doing this, now I am. Thank you